# Python Index Error: string index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
## A little helper program that capitalizes the first letter of a word
def Cap (s):
    s = s.upper()[0]+s[1:]
    return s
```

Giving me this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\prov-dc\students\jadewusi\crack2.py", line 447, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "\\prov-dc\students\jadewusi\crack2.py", line 398, in main
    foundit = search_method_3("passwords.txt")
  File "\\prov-dc\students\jadewusi\crack2.py", line 253, in search_method_3
    ourguess_pass = Cap(ourguess_pass)
  File "\\prov-dc\students\jadewusi\crack2.py", line 206, in Cap
    s = s.upper()[0]+s[1:]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: This means `s` is an empty string. You'll have to figure out why `ourguess_pass` is empty.

Comment: what is your entry 's'?

Answer (score 4):

As others have already noted, the problem is that you're trying to access an item in an empty string. Instead of adding special handling in your implementation, you can simply  use [`capitalize`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.capitalize):

```
'hello'.capitalize()
=> 'Hello'
''.capitalize()
=> ''
```

Comment: The OP's error clearly indicates that the string with which he is attempting to work is empty. At the moment, this is not a solution to the problem as it ignores the real issue thus will not work either.

Comment: capitalize won't throw an error though, it'll just return the empty string (which seems like reasonable behavior in the given use case), so I would argue this is a clear improvement over the approach OP presented.

Comment: This isn't quite the same as what the OP's code does when it works, though.  The OP's code capitalizes the first letter but leaves the rest alone.  Calling `.capitalize()` lowercases the remaining letters too.  For those of us whose family names have two capital letters, as in `MacGregor` or `O'Sullivan`, this can be very annoying.

Answer (score 3):

It blows up, presumably, because there is no indexing an empty string.

```
>>> ''[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

And as it has been pointed out, splitting a string to call `str.upper()` on a single letter can be supplanted by `str.capitalize()`.

Additionally, if you should regularly encounter a situation where this would be passed an empty string, you can handle it a couple of ways:

```
…#whatever previous code comes before your function
if my_string:
    Cap(my_string)    #or str.capitalize, or…
```

`if my_string` being more or less like `if len(my_string) > 0`.

And there's always ye old `try/except`, though I think you'll want to consider ye olde refactor first:

```
#your previous code, leading us to here…
try:
    Cap(my_string)
except IndexError:
    pass
```

I wouldn't stay married to indexing a string to call `str.upper()` on a single character, but you may have a unique set of reasons for doing so. All things being equal, though, `str.capitalize()` performs the same function.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = 'macGregor'
>>> s.capitalize()
'Macgregor'
>>> s[:1].upper() + s[1:]
'MacGregor'
>>> s = ''
>>> s[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
>>> s[:1].upper() + s[1:]
''
```

---

> Why does s[1:] not bail on an empty string?

[Tutorial on strings](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) says:

> Degenerate slice indices are handled gracefully: an index that is too
>   large is replaced by the string size, an upper bound smaller than the
>   lower bound returns an empty string.

See also [Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/4279).

Comment: +1 I like that. Why does `s[1:]` not bail on an empty string?

Comment: The error message mentioned by the OP appears also when the string is not empty. I just printed out the string argument right after entering the function and before accessing it by using `[ ]` and it printed out the string that most certainly was not empty.

Comment: @rbaleksandar: `s[0]` raises IndexError only for empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error while I was *sure* that my string wasn't empty. So I thought I'd share this here, so people who get that error have as many potentional reasons as possible.

In my case, I declared a one character string, and python apparently saw it as a char type. It worked when I added another character. I don't know why it doesn't convert it automatically, but this might be a reason that causes an "IndexError: string index out of range", even if you think that the supposed string is not empty.

It might differ between Python versions, I see the original question refers to Python 3. I used Python 2.6 when this happened.